# 404 on slug in django

Tags: python, django, slug

I am following a tutorial where they do something like this:

```
<a href="{ % url 'films:add_comment' slug=film.slug %}">Leave a comment</a>
```

They use slug. I have not been doing that, but have been referencing an ID. The parts of my code which I think are important to this are:

films/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path
from . import views


    app_name = 'films'
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.index, name='index'),
        url(r'^films/<int:film_id>/comment/', views.add_comment, name='add_comment'),
        path('films/<int:film_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    ]
```

films/views.py

```
def add_comment(request, film_id):
    film = get_object_or_404(Film, pk=film_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit = False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect('film:detail',film)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
        template = 'films/add_comment.html'
        context = {'form':form}
        return render (request,template,context)
```

mysite/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^accounts/',include('accounts.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('films.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

add_comment.html:

```
{% extends 'base_layout.html' %}
{% block content %}

<div class="create-comment">
    <h2>Add Comment</h2>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

If I click the link I made which is: `<a href="{ % url 'films:add_comment' film.id %}">Leave a comment</a>`

I get this:
[image]

And if I manually alter the url to

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/films/2/comment/

I get this:

[image]

But it looks like url 3 in that list matches what I typed?

Comment: in your url namespaces, is there a difference between `film` and `films`? for example, I see `'films:add_comment'` and `'film:detail'`

Comment: my file structure is films/templates/films/add_comment.html. If I do {{ film.title }} it displays the title of an individual film.

Comment: it should be films:detail. with that amended the same 404's stand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are so close. Just some minor mistakes I believe:

**(Final Working Edit)**

films/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [ 
   path('', views.index, name='index'), 
   path('<int:film_id>/comment', views.add_comment, name='add_comment'), 
   path('<int:film_id>', views.detail, name='detail'), 
]
```

mysite/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [ 
   url('films/', include('films.urls')), 
   url('accounts/',include('accounts.urls')), 
   url('admin/', admin.site.urls), 
]
```

**(Working out)**

---

films/urls.py:

```
app_name = 'films'
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^films/(?P<film_id>\d+)/comment/', views.add_comment, name='add_comment'),
]
```

Notice: `(?P<film_id>\d+)` that's how you capture the correct identifier

---

This is incorrect:

`<a href="{ % url 'films:add_comment' film.id %}">Leave a comment</a>`

It should be:

`<a href="{% url 'films:add_comment' film_id=film.id %}">Leave a comment</a>`

- Notice there is no gap in `{%`
- and we now use the identifier we defined in urls.py above.

---

Your `def add_comment(request, film_id):` has me a tad confused, however give my suggestions a shot. Then comment with any issues that occurred and we'll solve this!

---

EDIT: Ok next mini-errors that might be holding you back

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    path(r'^films/<int:film_id>/comment/$', views.add_comment, name='add_comment'),
    path(r'^films/<int:film_id>/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
]
```

- Make all the first arg strings regex strings i.e. `'foo'` -> `r'foo'`
- According to [the v2 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/#simplified-url-routing-syntax), you need to use `path( )` to use your cool `<int:film_id>` syntax. `url()` will not do it sadly ☹️
- End your regexes with a '$', it means end of string. Prevents matching `films/2/comment` to `films/2/`

Comment: I agree with this answer, but I think the way he captures `film_id` is now valid in Django 2

Comment: I think progress is being made :).... I now get this: `NoReverseMatch at /films/2/
Reverse for 'add_comment' with keyword arguments '{'film_id': 2}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['films/<int:film_id>/comment/']`

Comment: Would you add an edit with the full urls.py file please?

Comment: Sure, I have added all that I now have in this. At the time of screen shot I also have results and vote but was not using them.

Comment: I am getting the same 404 error unfortunately, but with the latest suggestion I now get the 404 on every page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163991/discussion-between-splatmistro-and-dan).